# spring cloud zuul static routes with circuit breaker

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, circuit-breaker

I have configured Zuul with static routes to other micro services. Is there a way to enable CircuitBreaker when calling out to other services?

Answer (score 1):

As you said Zuul will automatically wrap every routes inside `Ribbon` and `Hystrix`. But it's also quite easy to integrate with `Ribbon` and `Hystrix` between microservices. You can also use `Feign` to handle REST calls.

Imagine you have two services `serviceA` and `serviceB`, and that you want `serviceA` to call `serviceB` using `Ribbon` and `Hystrix`. Let's assume you have `Eureka` server running on the `localhost` and default port (`8761`)

### serviceA

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class ServiceAapplication{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceAapplication.class, args);
    }
}

@RestController()
@RequestMapping("/rest")
class DummyRestController{

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/hello")
    String hello(){
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

### ServiceB

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@EnableFeignClients
public class ServiceBapplication{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceBapplication.class, args);
    }
}

@FeignClient(value = "serviceA") //must be same name as the service name in Eureka
@RibbonClient(name = "serviceA") //must be same name as the service name in Eureka
interface ServiceAClient {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/rest/hello")
        String helloFromServiceA();
 }

@RestController()
@RequestMapping("/foo")
class DummyRestController{

    private final ServiceAclient client;

    @Autowired
    DummyRestController(ServiceAclient client){
        this.client = client;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/bar")
    String hello(){
        return client.helloFromServiceA();
    }
}
```

Now if you do a GET on serviceB with `foo/bar` it will use:

- Eureka to find the host and port for `serviceA`
- Ribbon to load balance between multiple instances of `serviceA`
- The whole thing is wrapped into a `Hystrix` command

Because of the `@EnableCircuitBreaker` annotation, your `serviceB` will expose a `Hystrix` stream. If you run a `HystrixDashboard` server you can connect to this stream and you will see a `helloFromServiceA` command on the dashboard.

You can configure `Ribbon` and `Hystrix` in your usual configuration file or using a separate configuration class in the `@FeignClient` and `@RibbonClient` annotations. You can find more info [here](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html)

**Important**: If you want `Ribbon` to retry on a different instance during a timeout, make sure the `Hystrix` timeout is higher than the `Ribbon` time out. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37280765/1738252)